# lightbox refresh Action

Tags: jquery, drupal-6, lightbox2

I have a form made using Webform[Drupal] which I load on the lightbox.

The structure of the site is in AJAX format.

When the form is submitted correctly there is no problem. But when any validation fails, the page is refreshed! Even if I check validations using JS, the captcha causes a problem when not entered correctly, makes the page to reload.

Once the page reloads it goes to the home page..

I want to have the form open in the page where it was left in the lightbox.. That is when its refreshed, the form should show up in lightbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it using [Ajax Captcha](http://ajaxcaptchas.com/)

The trick is to avoid any kind of reload.